# "projects" folder not showing in Visual studio code (left side tree or explorer tree)

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, angular-library

I have angular project running in visual studio code. I want to add an angular library. I created the library and I can see that angular has created `projects` folder in the root directly (sibling to `src` folder).

But for some reason, I'm not able to see it in Visual studio explorer or left-pane tree.

I checked `tsConfig` file and other configuration file and tried to change some settings but still `projects` folder doesn't appear in the tree.

What is being missed ?

is there any configuration to VSC settings that we need to set ?

**in root directory it is there**

[image]

**but not appearing in VSC**

[image]

`node_moduels` is also hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have hidden settings in vs code, Remove it from section `Files: Exclude`

`File > Preferences > Settings > [Search for exclude in the search bar] > Files: Exclude`

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't resolve the problem.